# Основной принцип работы Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Начал изучать `Redux` для использования в связке с `React`. Я понял что `Redux` только управляет состояниями, но мне не удается восстановить поток выполнения для простого примера. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как он работает в духе `1... 2... 3...`. Спасибо.

Есть несколько файлов:

```
app.js:

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <BookList />
        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Тут все понятно, но вот второй файл использующий `Redux` вызывает затруднения.

```
book-list.js:

class BookList extends Component {

  renderList() {
    return this.props.books.map((book) => {
      return (
        <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group clo-sm-4">
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

В особености `mapStateToProps` и последняя строка импорта.

И есть редюсер:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

И `index.js`

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

И `reduser_books.js`

```
export default function() {
  return [
    { title : 'Javascript'},
    { title : 'Java'},
    { title : 'C#'},
    { title : 'Goggle Go'},
    { title : 'Python'}
  ]
}
```

Как я понял этот код иллюстрирует самый простой пример связки `React-Redux`. Как его правильно прочесть?

Comment: кода BooksReducer  не хватает для полноты еще. и действий (actions), если они у вас есть

Comment: @PashaPash♦ да вы правы спасибо за подсказку. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: пример достаточно странный. redux - это цикл "стейт + действие => reducer => новый стейт". а у вас нет действий и нет изменения стейта. т.е. redux у вас в примере не раскрыт, по этому коду не получится сказать "redux тут нужен для управления стейтом по таком-то принципу"

Comment: Посмотрите курс Дениса Абрамова, он тут объясняет как устроены функции `redux` и `react-redux` изнутри и как их правильно применять https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: @Igor Golovin да я вот как раз по курсу и иду, только на английском треть слов выпадает и когда идет обсуждение сложных моментов начинаются проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Магия" начинает с компонента `<Provider>`. Его основная задача -- пробросить `store` во все компоненты приложения. Делает он это с помощью [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). React Context позволяет определить данные доступные дочерним компонентам. Напрямую React Context вы не используете в приложение, но его использует функция `connect`.

`combineReducers` - занимается объединением редьюсеров, создавая каждому редьюсеру отдельное место в `state`. При инициализации редьюсеров они возвращают свое начальное состояние, которое и помещается в общий `state` приложения. В вашем случае редьюсер всегда возвращает массив книг (что не совсем правильно с точки зрения Redux), поэтому этот массив и будет присвоен как начальное значение для `state.books`.

Функция `connect` делает очень много работы. Основные ее задачи:

1. Подписка на изменения `state` для перерисовки компонента
2. Передача необходимых значений из общего state приложения в компонент через props
3. Передача `Action Creators` в компонент через props

Как это все работает:
в функции `mapStateToProps` вы определяете, какие данные из общего `state` вам нужны в данном компоненте. Функция на входе получает общий `state` приложения, а возвращает выбранные вами отдельные данные, после чего эти данные будут присвоены как `this.props` в компоненте. По сути эта функция определяет отображения `state` на ваш компонент. В вашем случаем вы возвращаете из функции `{books: state.books}`, т.е. вы говорите что хотите чтобы в компоненте `this.props.books` было равно `state.books` (а как мы помним `state.books` получило массив книг из редьюсера при инициализации).

Примерно с помощью такого же отображения функция `connect` подключает и `Action Creators`, но у вас их нет.

Также коннект подписывается на изменения `state` приложения и в случаи его изменения проверяет, изменились ли данные на которые вы подписаны через `mapStateToProps` и если они изменились, меняет `props` что по умолчанию вызывает перерисовку компонента в react.

Функция `connect` работает через [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) создавая компонент-обертку поверх вашего компонента (что хорошо видно через [React DevTools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)) и подключается к `react context` созданный `<Provider>` для получения `store`

Поскольку у все нет экшенов и `state` приложения не меняется, на этом жизненный цикл вашего приложения заканчивается.

Comment: По вашей же ссылке
_If you aren’t familiar with state management libraries like [Redux or MobX, don’t use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context)._

Comment: @Pavel так не используйте контекст, зачем он вам?

Comment: Вы написали что redux прокидывает контекст в компоненты и привели ссылку на документацию, в которой написано что библиотеки такие как redux и mobx не используют context

Comment: @Pavel я такого в доках не читал. Если что фраза `If you aren’t familiar with state management libraries like Redux or MobX, don’t use context.` Переводится как: `Если вы не знакомы с библиотеками управляющие состоянием приложения такими как Redux или MobX, то не используйте контекст.`